# Django: override form validation to get around this error

Tags: python, django

My specific problem is detailed below, but the main point of my question is this: When I click "Save" on the Django admin form while editing a model, what happens? What is the order of the validation/save process? How can I override these methods to solve my problem below, which is to say updating an intermediate table at the appropriate time as a workaround for the issue I described?

I'm working on a Django application which is facing a PostgreSQL database. The database is relatively large, and I have a lot of many-to-many relationships. The one that I am currently having an issue with is the n:m relationship between People and Sources.

The app is used mainly by non-technical people to add to the database through Django's built-in admin feature. The primary issue that I was having when I started working on the app was severe page slowdown when editing a Person on the admin site. If the person  had too many Sources, each drop-down in the TabularInline representation of sources loaded thousands of entries. I found a workaround and overrode the `get_formfield_for_foreignkey()` method as follows:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    field = super(SourceMaterialInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs) 

    # We will overwrite this method to ONLY return relevant materials on this person
    materials     = SourceMaterial.objects.all() 
    materials_p   = SourceMaterial.people.through.objects.all() 
    person_ID     = get_ID_from_path(request.path)
    if not_integer(person_ID):
        return field
    materials_pid = materials_p.filter(person_id=person_ID) 

    # The next step is to use these relevant materials to obtain the SourceMaterial objects from the SourceMaterial table 
    relevant_ids = []
    for mat in materials_pid:
        relevant_ids += [mat.sourcematerial_id] 
    relevant_materials = materials.filter(id__in=relevant_ids) 

    # now we can set the queryset so that only relevant materials are included
    field.queryset = relevant_materials

    return field
```

So this accomplishes what I wanted. When you go to edit a Person object through the Admin page, the dropdown menus to select sources only load and display Sources that belong to that Person.

The problem this creates, however, is when I go to add a new Source via the Person change form. I would like to keep this functionality, but it is now broken.

If I go to add a new source, a pop-up window appears. I select the file on my machine, give it a name and click add. At this point it is added to the Sources table, but not to the intermediate table linking it to this Person. When I go to save the Person, the form asks me to correct this error: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

Here is the pop-up: [Add new source material pop-up for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzYT.png)

This makes sense, as there is no established link between the Person and the Source yet. So instead I try adding the Person ID as well when adding a source this way, and the error is: Sourcematerial-person relationship with this Sourcematerial and Person already exists. I'm assuming this is because when I add the Source with the Person ID, the intermediate table is populated appropriately, and when I go to save, it tries to add the source again, because the form detects it as being new.

I'm hoping I can override form validation/saving so that I can keep functionality of adding a Source to the database this way. If anybody has any suggestions as to what exactly I could override (I was very confused by the docs) or another work around, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It is a good idea to ask your question (How do I get X to do Y ...?) in the first paragraph, or the last. Folks will keep reading if they need more context.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added a paragraph at the beginning with some more concrete questions.